# MPMoviePlayerViewController is not playing .mp4 Video in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, media-player, mpmovieplayercontroller

i have

```
import MediaPlayer
```

declared

```
var moviePlayer: MPMoviePlayerViewController = MPMoviePlayerViewController()
```

and on action of play button this code gets called

```
let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: String(format: "%@",self.videoListArray[indexPath!.row].url!))!
    self.moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerViewController(contentURL: url)
    self.moviePlayer.moviePlayer.fullscreen = true
    self.moviePlayer.moviePlayer.repeatMode = .None
    self.moviePlayer.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceType.Streaming
    self.presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated(self.moviePlayer)
```

but the movie player comes shows Black screen and Loading after some second comes back to the ViewController again.

Comment: have you try to create NSURL like `let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath`

Comment: You can try moviePlayer.prepareToPlay() before using play method.

Comment: Thanks but i have tried `moviePlayer.prepareToPlay()` but no success

Comment: Thanks Nitin but i'm using Web urls not the local files.

Answer (score 0):

`MPMoviePlayerViewController` is deprecated in iOS 9.0, so better use `AVPlayerViewController`. To play your local videos all you need is create a new `viewController` as `AVPlayerViewController` and use the `VC`'s `player`.

```
import AVKit
import AVFoundation 

class MyViewController: AVPlayerViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

      if let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Sample", ofType: "mp4") {
            let avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
            avPlayerLayer.frame = self.view.frame
            view.layer .addSublayer(avPlayerLayer)
            let steamingURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)//note here, you need to use fileURLWithPath instead of string: for local files
            //let steamingURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.")//this is for web urls
            player = AVPlayer(URL: steamingURL)
            player!.play()
        }
    }
}
```